# Java send parameter to method paint

Tags: java

in my class draw Shape i want to send parameter to method paint like

```
 g.drawRect (a, b, 200, 200);
```

how can i implement my code

```
class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect (10, 10, 200, 200);  
  }
}

public class drawShape {

  public drawShape(){
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
    window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all, do you just want to call paint method or you need to add parameters to paint function?

Comment: Can you concretize your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `paint` is called from EDT every time the component needs to be repainted. And parameters of drawing should be considered as the properties of the `MyCanvas`.
For example:

```
class MyCanvas extends JComponent {
    int a,b;
    public void setProps(int a, int b) {
        this.a=a; this.b=b;
        repaint();//mark this component to be repainted
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawRect (a, b, 200, 200);
    }

  static public void main(String args[]){
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
    MyCanvas canvas=new MyCanvas();
    canvas.setProps(20,40);
    window.getContentPane().add(canvas);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: i need to call setprops from another class wat can i do

Comment: i other class i create object like d1 = new drawShape();

Comment: and i need to use d1.setprops it can't

Comment: You need to call `setProps` on created canvas (you have to keep reference). Make `MyCanvas canvas` a global field of some "main class".
Then make call `canvas.setProps(x,y)` when needed - that is on some event - like user input event, or timer.